# Column comparison for a specific instance in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a sample data, and I want to verify that `Age_Low` is less than `Age_High` just for a specific instance.

```
  ID   NAME   Age_Low   Age_High
  1    ABC     50         100
  1    ABC     25          60
  1    ABC     75          90
  2    XYZ     20          40
  2    XYZ     50          20
```

For example for above data, every instance of ABC should have `Age_Low` less than `Age_High`, if not it should return as a result.

I tried following query, but it is returning all the ABC rows because `Age_Low` is higher than `Age_High` in some rows.

```
  SELECT *
  FROM tablename
  WHERE Age_Low > Age_High
```

Comment: Do you want just the name or the whole rows as result?

Comment: @jarlh whole row as result

Comment: In your sample data *no* row has `Age_Low > Age_High`, which makes for bad sample data.

Comment: I'd go with `NOT EXISTS`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, Nick I modified my sample data.. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: So what is wrong with your query? It correctly returns the row which has XYZ, 50, 20 as its data

Comment: So you want only names where all `Age_Low` are < all `Age_High`?

Comment: @Nick It is returning ABC values as well since Age_low 75 is higher than Age_High 60 in its previous instance.

Comment: No, that's not how SQL works. Unless this is not the query you're actually using, `Age_Low` and `Age_High` will only ever be compared in the same row, not across rows. With the data and query you've given, no row where `Name = 'ABC'` can be in the result set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to select rows where `Age_Low` is greater than the smallest value of `Age_High` for that value of `ID`. If so, this query will do what you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename t
WHERE Age_Low > (SELECT MIN(Age_High)
                 FROM tablename t1
                 WHERE t1.ID = t.ID)
```

Output:

```
ID  NAME    Age_Low     Age_High
1   ABC     75          90
2   XYZ     50          20
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @Nick!

Answer (score 1):

You seem want :

```
select t.*
from table t
where not exists (select 1 from table t1 where t1.id = t.id and t1.name = t.name and t1.Age_Low < t.Age_High);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * from t where Age_Low > 
(

select min(Age_High) from t where NAME='ABC'
)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.